# Convert an ArrayList to 2 dimensional array initialization error

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have my code here and what I'm trying to do is to store a whole file into a list.

Then add ii to two dimensional array, but without compiling this code, editor(Eclipse) shows me "the local variable 'data' may not have been initialized" at the line 11.

```
ArrayList < String > listData = new ArrayList < String > ();
String[][] data;
int listSize;
Scanner input = new Scanner(studentFile);
while (input.hasNext()) {
    listData.add(input.nextLine());
}
listSize = listData.size();
for (int x = 0; x < listSize; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        data[x][x] = listData.get(y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
String[][] data ;
```

With:

```
String[][] data = new String[listSize][] ;
```

And place this line after:

```
listSize = listData.size();
```

Comment: You are right but actual what I want is to store each student's info to each row and adds those 10 information to the column of my 2d array. But each element in listdata is assigned to one information only so if I use listSize as my row for the array it's going to be much bigger than I want.